# Wicket getPath returns just the id

Tags: java, path, wicket

I am trying to get the path of my Wicket-Component, but it is always returning just the id when calling `componentName.getPath()`.

Actually is the return value of `getPath()` the same as `getId()`.

What could be the problem and how to get the path?

My goal is to update a Labelfield when the entry in another combobox field changes, so that it take the new value. Both fields are on the same page but on different panels. I tried to get the path to that labelelement, but unfortunately I am getting always this exception: 
Last cause: Behavior redb.main.modules.sample.view.details.pck.PackageCharacterizationPanel$9 can only be added to an instance of a `FormComponent`

I did that:

```
add(new ComboBoxField<String>("name", fieldLabel("name")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public IModel<List<String>> provideChoices() {
            return packageNameChoices;
        }
    }.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(getPage().get("sample_details.logistic.package.label"));

        }
    }));`
```

Comment: Are you calling #getPath() in the constructor? When the component is not yet added to the component tree, the method will just return the component's id.

Comment: yes.. but it is a panel, i cannot call it outside the constructor.. all the methods that are outside the constructor, are called already in the constructor. :/

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBoxField` must not be extending wicket's `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent<T>` and this is why you're getting the exception.

Comment: This is the reason for  the exception you said you're getting - " Last cause: Behavior redb.main.modules.sample.view.details.pck.PackageCharacterizationPanel$9 can only be added to an instance of a FormComponent"